# Where's my module gone?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

```
    make -C /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9 M=`pwd` 

  LD      /root/test/lkm/built-in.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9'

    make -C /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.9 M=`pwd` modules_install

  INSTALL /root/test/lkm/try.ko
  DEPMOD  2.6.32.9
```

But when I `lsmod |grep try`,nothing is shown,why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INSTALL` doesn't load the module, it just copies it to its final location.  Try `insmod /root/test/lkm/try.ko`.

Comment: What kind of benifits are there to copy the module there?

Comment: @assem: `insmod` doesn't copy it anywhere, it just loads the module, i.e. just what you want.

Comment: `modprobe` probably expects to find it there, if you set things up for autoloading.  It's also where `mkinitrd` looks for modules needed to boot.